# How to prevent table row from re-sizing when hidden text is displayed?

Tags: html, css

I have this box that appears as a hint box when you hover the parent element. On implementing the same code outside a table cell there are no problems but in a table cell the entire row re-sizes on hovering the text since new text is added to the row.

How can I prevent that?

HTML:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0px" class="dtable">
<tr id="th">
<td>Name</td>
<td>-</td>
<td>-</td>
<td>-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hoverbox">Some text<span>Hidden text</span></td>
<td>-</td>
<td>-</td>
<td>-</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
# CSS for the table
.dtable {
     margin: 0px auto;
     border:1px solid #ccc;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     text-align: center;
     border-color: black;
     font-weight: bold;
     width: 100%;
}

.dtable tr:nth-child(odd){background-color:#303030}
.dtable tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#333333}

.dtable #th {
     background-color: #000;
     font-family: eurostile;
}

.dtable td {
     padding: 15px 0px;
     font-family: eurostile;
}

# CSS for the hidden text
.hoverbox span {
    background:#F8F8F8;
    border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: -80px;
    left:-30px;
    display: none;
    #padding:0 20px;
}

.hoverbox span:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px; 
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-10px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}

.hoverbox:hover span {
    display:block;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9dx0mng/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean when the hidden tooltip is displayed on hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet

```css
.dtable {
  margin: 0px auto;
     border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  border-color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
}

.dtable tr:nth-child(odd){background-color:#303030}
.dtable tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#333333}

.dtable #th {
     background-color: #000;
  font-family: eurostile;
}

.dtable td {
     padding: 15px 0px;
  font-family: eurostile;
}

.hoverbox span {
    background:#F8F8F8;
    border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: -80px;
    left:-30px;
    display: none;
    #padding:0 20px;
}

.hoverbox span:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px; 
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-10px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}

.hoverbox:hover span {
    display:block;
     position:absolute;
     z-index: 9;
     top: 0;
     left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0px" class="dtable">
  <tr id="th">
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="hoverbox">Some text<span>Hidden text</span></td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You have to add the absolute position to the span itself, not to `.hoverbox span:after`, like this:

```
.hoverbox:hover span {
    display:block;
     position:absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Ok this seems to be working perfectly in preview snippet and stuff but for some reason it is not working on my browser (chrome) when I save it on my PC

Comment: @M4Shooter did you add the css rules I added at the bottom?

Comment: @M4Shooter it works well in jsfiddle and in this snippet. Please make sure you have properly set the dimensions and position for the tooltip. I really cannot think of anything else right now

Comment: Oh found the snag.. the tool tip was displaying somewhere at the top of the webpage due to top: 0;, fixed now. And thanks for your help! this worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `position: relative` on the `td` and `absolute` on the tooltip. Try this  (I set the position to 0,0 so you can see it):

```css
.dtable {
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  border-color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
}

.dtable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #303030
}

.dtable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #333333
}

.dtable #th {
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: eurostile;
}

.dtable td {
  padding: 15px 0px;
  font-family: eurostile;
}

.hoverbox span {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
  color: #717171;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  #padding: 0 20px;
}

.hoverbox {
  position: relative;
}

.hoverbox span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #dfdfdf;
  border-right: 5px solid #dfdfdf;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hoverbox:hover span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0px" class="dtable">
  <tr id="th">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hoverbox">Some text<span>Hidden text</span></td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change in the css:

```
display: none;
```

with

```
visibility: hidden;
```

and

```
display: block;
```

with

```
visibility: visible;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `display:none`, it's like you remove the element and it is not exist and when you show it by setting `display:block`, it's like you add that element inside your HTML

**You have two ways to do this:**

1. Set position of `td` to `relative`, and position of your `tooltip` to `absolute`. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f9dx0mng/3/)

just add these to your style:

```
td{
  position:relative;
}

span{
  //Tooltip
  position:absolute;
}
```

2. Use css **`visibility`**, it is like hiding an element! [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f9dx0mng/7/)

Comment: This too again changes the size of the cell the <span> is embedded into. The cell looks ugly with that..

Comment: @M4Shooter You can style them easily. Which way you want to use?

Comment: Not styling, it's that the text in the tool tip still occupies some space in the cell on display: block; .. the cell is supposed to stay static

Comment: @M4Shooter Try this play, https://jsfiddle.net/f9dx0mng/6/ And what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your css code must be like this

```
    .dtable {
     margin: 0px auto;
     border:1px solid #ccc;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     text-align: center;
     border-color: black;
     font-weight: bold;
     width: 100%;
}

.dtable tr:nth-child(odd){background-color:#303030}
.dtable tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#333333}

.dtable #th {
     background-color: #000;
     font-family: eurostile;
}

.dtable td {
     padding: 15px 0px;
     font-family: eurostile;
}

.hoverbox span {
    background:#F8F8F8;
    border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: -60px;
    left:-30px;
    visibility: hidden;
    #padding:0 20px;
}

.hoverbox span:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px; 
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right:5px solid #dfdfdf;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-10px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}

.hoverbox:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: This is still changing the size of the first cell it is embedded into